# Convert timestamp to datetime instance

Tags: php, datetime

I am having the following PHP setup:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2017 21:10:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86
 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

I am using xampp, so I am running a `32-bit version` on my `64-bit windows 8.1`  machine.

I would like to convert the following timestamp into a Datetime instance:

```
$timestamp = 1546438627830;
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$timestamp);
echo $t;
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

I was thinking that my 32-bit PHP version might cause some issues. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Thx in advance for your reply!

**UPDATE**

After using var_dump() I get the following:

```
$timestamp = 1546438627830;
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$timestamp);
var_dump($t);
```

Output:

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(20) "50974-09-09 05:30:30"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(1)
  public $timezone =>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

As you can see the wrong timestamp is converted?

Any suggestions why?

**UPDATE**

After trying several things I found the following solution:

```
$timestamp = 1546438627830;
$result = date ('c', (int) round ($timestamp / 1000));
$msec = (int) $timestamp % 1000;
$t = strtotime(str_replace ('+00:00', sprintf (".%03dZ", $msec), $result));

$finalTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $t);

var_dump($finalTime);
```

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @Alex I printed the `var_dump` output, however I still get the wrong value for the timestamp. Any suggestions why?

Comment: year value equal to `50974` technically it is not wrong, it is just weird and you just don't expect it. Once you can explain why you expect different result - you will be able to answer your question yourself next time and will realize why it is obvious for some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `echo` on an object, PHP tries to call the magic `__toString()` method on that object. If it can't do that, it will throw the error you get. I recommend using `var_dump()` to debug objects.

https://3v4l.org/GlJaW

```
<?php

$timestamp = 1546438627830;
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$timestamp);
var_dump($t);
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

EDIT: Handling milliseconds

```
<?php

$timestamp = (int)(1546438627830 / 1000);
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$timestamp);
var_dump($t);
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! I used `var_dump` to "debug" the timestamp. However, still I get the wrong output? I kindly ask for your opinion what might be the reason for this? How to correctly parse it?

Comment: @Anna.Klee Well your timestamp is in milliseconds. Try the edit. Make sure to read the documentation page to `DateTime::createFromFormat`. The `U` modifier means **seconds** since the unix epoch, not milliseconds. Thus the weird behavior.